# Getting 2 Local Times for User

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is for example if the local time is `6:00PM` I would like to display the time 10 minutes ahead which would be `6:10PM` and for the other time I would like to go 50 minutes back from the current time so that would be `5:10PM`.. what I have so far does neither since I can only figure out how to display the current time

```
<script>
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()


var suffix = "AM";
if (hours >= 12) {
suffix = "PM";
hours = hours - 12;
}
if (hours == 0) {
hours = 12;
}

if (minutes < 10)
minutes = "0" + minutes

document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</b>")
</script>
```

How do I go back 50 minutes and ahead 10 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice

```
<script>
    var futureTime = new Date();
    futureTime.setMinutes(futureTime.getMinutes()+10);

    var pastTime = new Date();
    pastTime.setMinutes(pastTime.getMinutes()-50);
</script>
```

Then just use the pastTime and futureTime variables with your existing display code.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Downvoted for w3schools.com reference. Use MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: A much better resource. I added the link for the first thing I hit in google when I cross referenced my answer.

Comment: @BarryCarlyon same thing with this answer too.. when I paste this into my code it doesnt work.. how am I suppose to use this?

Comment: This is just a quick note to let you know that I edited the answer to reflect the more authoritative MDN instead of w3schools. When my edit is approved I should be able to change my vote, at which point I will upvote your answer, because I believe it's much more elegant than the other one.

Comment: @JoeBobby all I have done is shown you how to calculate the two times you asked for. It's up to you what to do with the futureTime and pastTime variables. Essentially substitute my two variables into the code you already pasted (well you would need two instances of your whole code and swap the variable accordingly). Which I assumed is not the full code in use. IE I have guided you towards the full answer, but giving you the minimum required. That way you learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatDate(d)
{
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();
    var suffix = "AM";

    if (hours >= 12)
    {
        suffix = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours == 0)
    {
        hours = 12;
    }

    if (minutes < 10)
    {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }

    return hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;
}

var currentTime = new Date();

var futureTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime());
futureTime.setMinutes(futureTime.getMinutes() + 10);

var pastTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime());
pastTime.setMinutes(pastTime.getMinutes() - 50);

document.write("<b>" + formatDate(currentTime) + "</b>");
document.write("<b>" + formatDate(futureTime) + "</b>");
document.write("<b>" + formatDate(pastTime) + "</b>");
```

Comment: I added this wrapped in `<script>...</script>` tags and its not displaying.. is there anythign I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should add back the print time logic. I've updated the answer, please have a look.